# Multiple Choices PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I made a multiple choice with PHP (Codeigniter) and MySQL. I Got trouble when trying to retrieve value from the answer (with dynamic name) for each question. Here is the code for radio button :

```
<input type="radio" name="question_id (according to id of question)" value="answer_id">
```

So, if I have 3 random questions, the structure will be

```
<p>Question number 1 goes here</p>
<input type="radio" name="question_id1[]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="question_id1[]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="question_id1[]" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="question_id1[]" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="question_id1[]" value="5">


<p>Question number 6 goes here</p>
<input type="radio" name="question_id6[]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="question_id6[]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="question_id6[]" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="question_id6[]" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="question_id6[]" value="5">


<p>Question number 9 goes here</p>
<input type="radio" name="question_id9[]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="question_id9[]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="question_id9[]" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="question_id9[]" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="question_id9[]" value="5">
```

How to retrieve the answer that relates to the question ? For example put it in Array like :

```
array p = ['id_question' => 21, 'id_answer'=4]
```

[The radio button structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kByMr.png)

Comment: where is question_id?

Comment: Change your format from `name="question_id1[]"` to `name="question_id[1]"`. This way you can do a `foreach($_POST['question_id'] as $id => $answer)`

Comment: I would then also simply your answer array to `[id_question=>id_answer]`, ie. `$answers = [21=>4]`, so then using the `foreach()` in my last comment, `foreach($_POST['question_id'] as $id => $answer) { if ($answer==$answers[$id]) echo "You got Question #".$id." Correct!"; else echo "You got Question #".$id." Wrong!"; }`

Comment: Also tell that user can select single radio button or multiple radio button as for answer....

Comment: No, user can only choose one

Comment: Then try my answer it will work great..... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
<p>Question number 9 goes here</p>
<input type="radio" name="question_id[9]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="question_id[9]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="question_id[9]" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="question_id[9]" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="question_id[9]" value="5">
<p>Question number 6 goes here</p>
<input type="radio" name="question_id[6]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="question_id[6]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="question_id[6]" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="question_id[6]" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="question_id[6]" value="5">
```

And in server side

```
<?php
//assuming form method is post
$questions_array = array();
foreach($_POST[question_id] as $key=>$answer)
{
  $questions_array[] = array('id_question' => $key, 'id_answer'= $answer); 
}
print_r($questions_array);
?>
```

Assuming that user can select a single radio button for single question....

Comment: thanks so much.. I still get confused.. What $key=>$answer does here?

Comment: mark it as answer if it satisfies you... Look for '0' on left hand side and `tick mark` under it click on that....

Comment: I'll try it .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have placed the code in the form and with a submit button i submitted it. Then the output i got it is 
Array
(
    [question_id1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

```
[question_id6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
    )

[question_id9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

[submit] => submit
```

)
So we can access with the same name. I did it with normal php code. Because the array will that is formed will be same in both core php as well as codeigniter. So we can normally access it with for loop.